# A sensible universe for a fictional story

Tags: science-fiction, time-travel, paradox

I wouldn't call this scientifically accurate, but would like some opinion on sensibility of the idea.

As part of a story about two time travelling engineers, they discover that their own universe actually updates itself whenever a frontier in technology is crossed. So basically, the invention of time travel itself caused certain updates to support this new paradigm by offering system-wide resolutions to various time-travel induced paradoxes.

Now, I was wondering which direction to take when trying to offer an explanation - since this one does drive curiosities. I've got two ideas to branch out:

1. The universe is a living organism with a nucleus, mitochondria and RNA, and it is actually responding in a way that gene mutations occur.
2. The universe is an AI driven program, and is continuously updating a logical universe.

Which one of these would be more likely in case of a reactive universe? I'm trying to figure out a way to *know* this to be true from the character's perspective.

Comment: The bigger the roganism the more energy it need. So it woudl mean it's constatnly eating itself.  Which on itself, from a story perspective, is more important to than the fact that it's just update itself. Being it AI would be very similar to Lem story, movie 13th Floor or Matrix. The time travel and "update" to paradoxes mean that form the start you have multiverses. So with them anything goes as it's already there.

Comment: Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. You've asked a question that's out of scope (you might want to review our [help]). SE is not a discussion forum and you've asked a question that can't have an objective answer - and therefore can't have a best answer - which is what makes it out of scope. Which one makes most logical sense will vary person-to-person, so pick one and move forward. VTC:opinion-based. (BTW, you have a very clever idea. You might consider posting short stories about your universe [on our blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory). That would be cool.)

Comment: Honestly, doing a reality-check tagged question for how you think each of those two ideas would play out would be very appropriate. Try doing 2 separate questions along the lines of "This universe is a living creature and it updates itself like this, would this work?" "This universe is an AI driven program and updates itself like this, would this work?"

Comment: The universe could be a living organism, even a sentient one, without having mitochondria and DNA.

Answer (score 3):

A living vessel re-configuring itself based on the behaviour of it's occupants is something that occurs in fiction all the time. Some examples include Moya from Farscape (the ship), the Wraith Hive ships from Stargate Atlantis, and "The Cloud" from Star Trek Voyager. Expanding these "Ship or Nebula" sized organisms up to "Universe" size is not beyond my ability to suspend my disbelief, but I wouldn't suggest to use RNA / mitochondria / human definitions of life, a living being the size of a universe has issues with speed of light propagation of information, and by handwaving away the internals of how that life works you'll be able to suspend belief better.

My biggest issue with a living universe updating in response to what I've done is "Why do you care about little old me"? People have similar questions with religion topics (why does God care about my actions, I'm insignificant), and perhaps some "The universe loves you and wants the best for you" might help sell why the universe cares about what happens enough to update in response to them building a new thing in their garage.

Could also be a population of very large beings, rather than one singular being.

If the universe is a simulation with AI running the show, then this would explain the updates. You'd need to sell that we're in a simulation - perhaps temporary observed changes in planck distance as the simulation struggles with complex behaviour nearby so lowers the resolution of the simulation?

There's two other approaches Id suggest:

- Multi-verse theory, by the act of travelling back in time they move to a new universe, with different properties. So it appears that the universe is reconfiguring.
- Quantum trickery. I'd summarise Quantum mechanics as the more you examine what's going on, the more bizarre the universe gets.

Comment: The **Why** question is something that is pretty challenging. But I guess delving too deep into that may just take me off to another discussion. Could there be an alternative to a _caring_ universe? I'm not asking for an oppressive one either (like the Matrix).

Answer (score 1):

**AI and simulations**

If you're set on your 2 branches, the AI one makes most sense. The Singularity is an idea that people are uploading their conscious into a computer. In some ideas they retain their individuality. Alternatively it can be just like the Matrix. A fully simulated reality created to live out your lives. Lastly there are idea's that the universe is a simulation on the edge of a super massive black hole.

All of these have one thing in common. They are existing theories of how all of this could be a simulation. Simulations can be controlled and changed by AI.

A living organism however is very difficult to explain. It can't directly be observed in our universe, so it could be "living" throughout the multitude of dimensions. When time travelling, it would change the universe. However, this is much more hand-wavy than the actual existing theories of an AI simulating every experience.

Answer (score 0):

**Observing changes things**

I'm proposing a 3rd option.

The [double slit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) experiment shows us that observing things can change the properties. How and why lies in the quantum realm on which I've read a lot, but can't pretend to truly understand. As far as I read it, there is a form of uncertainty everywhere. When observing, this uncertainty collapses and resolves into a certainty. This whole experiment shows that this small difference of just observing has 2 wildly different outcomes. In one outcome it's like an energy wave in a sound wave kind of way. In the other one a particle, like ball thrown at something.

Possibly observing can go much further. The moment you can travel through time, different ways of observing are available. The universe doesn't change, but the act of time travel does change the outcome. Essentially "updating" the universe that happen to support your version of time travel.

As an aside, I once heard a theory that the moment we research and discover more about the universe, it gets more complex. Another way to perceive the observing changing the world around you.

Comment: I'm inclined to pick this one, since AI simulations are quite overdone. Apart from double slit, what experiments can I pick to get better understanding of the mechanics?

Comment: @HariMohan It's advised to let a question sit for at least 24h before picking an answer. There might be better ones. I hope someone else can give further suggestions for experiments and research of quantum physics, as I don't have the time right now.